# Jquery How to change visibility of span element on hover image

Tags: jquery

I have a simple HTML page where each images have a description, 
I'd like you doing hover over a particular image must display the specific description.
The class description of the CSS has been set  visibility: hidden;

I have prove but  But my jquery function on hover do not set the class visibility: visible;
I do not Know the exact syntax in jquery for  set the class of span element  in visibility:
visible;

```
<div id="FiltriMusica2">                            
  <p idsapore="1" class="sapore"><img alt="caffe.png" src="/caffe.png">
    <span class="descrizionesap">Adrenalina</span>
  </p>      
  <p idsapore="2" class="sapore"><img alt="peperoncino.png" src="/peperoncino.png">
    <span class="descrizionesap" >Peperoncino</span>            
  </p>                          
</div>
```

CSS

```
.descrizionesap {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

javascript

```
jQuery(".sapore").hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).children().find('.descrizionesap').css("visibility","visible");            
}, function() {                             
    jQuery(".descrizionesap").css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

Comment: You do not need JavaScript at all.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is enough for this task

```
.descrizionesap {
  visibility:hidden;
}   

/* if you want to show the span on image hover */
img:hover + .descrizionesap {
  visibility: visible;
}   

/* if you want to show the span on paragraph hover */
.sapore:hover .descrizionesap {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

both the examples work also on `IE7` (on `IE6` the :hover pseudoclass works only for link elements).

---

As a side note if you care to have validated markup, consider to change the attribute `idsapore` into something like `data-id-sapore`

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer states, you only need CSS to do it. But here's how you can do it in jQuery: using `display:block` and `display:none`.

CSS

```
.descrizionesap {
    display: none;
}
```

Now in jQuery, you can do:

```
$('.sapore').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.descrizionesap').css('display', 'block');
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.descrizionesap').css('display', 'none');
});
```